Strange cat behaviour
My cat is a male about 9 months old. He's been to the vet twice already for his vaccinations (his last appointment was four days ago). The veterinarian said he was super healthy, his food and water intake was normal and he’s doing great.
But for the last month, he’s been meowing all day, every day; maybe peeing or spraying everywhere in the house (no one has seen him do it, only smell it and see wet spots). He runs outside if someone opens the door so we’ve been having him around the front and back of the house with a leash on, it keeps him quiet and he likes to lay in the sun. He has attacked my dad on two different occasions after bringing him back into the house.
He used to be a very sweet and cuddly cat and I’m just confused about this sudden change. I’m worried something might be wrong with him that I’m not picking up on.

all of this is very normal for a young un neutered adult male cat that can go outside.your cat scent marking can be stopped or limited by neutering your cat,and you will probably save a lot of money in vet bills by neutering him.

@trondhansen judging by the upvote count on your comment it should probably an answer.

What you are asking about here is typical behaviour for an intact male cat,the loud meowing and scent marking is normal for an healhy intact male cat.
If you get your cat neutered he will be less likely to get into fights with other male cats and the scent marking and loud meowing will be reduced.
For a young adult cat the first spring and summer is special with new scents and smells that needs to be investigated,spring is the time of year when nature changes pace  and mating season starts for most animals.
Spring is a stressful time for most cats but if you neuter/spay your cat you will lower the stress level and make it less likely for your cat to end up in a fight and less likely for your cat to run away from home.
by stressful i mean every thing in nature happens at the same time in the spring so your cat will have too many things to explore and way too little time to do so.
I do not think your cat wanted to attack your father it is more likely that your cat resisted being captured and brought inside.
If you get your cat neutered you will make it less likely for your cat to get injured and thereby less likely to get innfections from other cats.
For female cats spaying will reduce the risk of mamarian and other types of cancer and it will reduce the risk of many types of innfections from other cats.
